# AD Permission denied when adding a user to a group in a trusted domain

Tags: active-directory

I have 2 domains with a two way trust between them. I want to modify a group on one of the domains but running on the other domain.

Lets say the domain I am running my script on is mydomain.com, and I would like to add a user to yourdomain.com

I tried through VBScript as well as DSMod, but get permission denied

```
dsmod group "CN=DCComics,OU=Comics,DC=yourdomain,DC=com" -addmbr "CN=Dark Knight,OU=Comics,DC=yourdomain,DC=com"
```

When I run the above, I get this

```
dsmod failed:CN=DCComics,OU=Comics,DC=yourdomain,DC=com:Insufficient access rights to perform the operation.
```

I'm able to query data on yourdomain.com and I have checked the trusts are working just fine. I have logged in as administrator on mydomain.com.

Ideally I am looking to do this in VBScript, so I wrote this just to test:

```
user = "LDAP://CN=Clark Kent,OU=Comics,DC=yourdomain,DC=com"
group = "LDAP://CN=DCComics,OU=Comics,DC=yourdomain,DC=com"
Dim objgroup
SET objGroup = GETOBJECT(group)
objGroup.Add(user)
```

Once again, I get an error about permissions:

```
C:\tmp\foo.vbs(6, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Permission denied
```

Any guidance where I need to muck about with permissions for this? Might I add, I am still learning about AD, so please be gentle :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being an admin in `mydomain.com` does not make you an admin in `Yourdomain.com` - trust or no trust.  You need your `mydomain\account` added to the `Administrators` group in `yourdomain.com`

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Just out of curiosity, would it work if I had logged into mydomain.com using yourdomain\administrator account? (I can't test this right now but will try when I get the chance)

Comment: Sure - that's what the trust buys you - cross login and permission sharing.  It does not grant additional rights by default.